# swipe refresh returning duplicate data

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

SwipeRefreshLayout is returning duplicate data when I refresh it, I have tried other solutions here but still not working. It's still duplicating my data when I refresh it.The data is retrieved correctly but the main issue is that it duplicates more and more whenever I refresh. I am using some sort of architecture for the app meaning that you might not be able to see where I did the api call and judging from the fact that the data has been retrieved from the server as requested so I don't think that there is any need for me to post those other code as the issue is only on duplicate data caused by swipe refresh layout. Here is my code

```
            public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            
                private RecyclerView recyclerView;
                private ProgressDialog pd;
                private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
                private List<MovieModel> moviesList;
                private HomeMovieAdapter adapter;
                private MovieListViewModel movieListViewModel;
                private FavouriteDbHelper favouriteDbHelper;
            
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
                    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_home);
                    swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_content_home);
                    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar_home);
                    favouriteDbHelper = new FavouriteDbHelper(this);
                    moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
                    movieListViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
                    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    
                    initViews();
            
                }
            
            private void initViews(){
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                    pd.setMessage("Fetching Movies...");
                    pd.setCancelable(false);
                    pd.show();
                    adapter = new HomeMovieAdapter(this,moviesList);
                    if (getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
                    }else {
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,4));
                    }
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_orange_dark);
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            initViews();
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Movies Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    observePopularMoviesRequest();
            }
            
                private void observePopularMoviesRequest(){
                    movieListViewModel.searchMoviesPage(1);
                    movieListViewModel.getPopularMovies().observe(this, new Observer<List<MovieModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<MovieModel> movieModels) {
                            try {
            
                                //getting the retrieved data from the api
                                if (movieModels !=null){
                                    for (MovieModel movieModel: movieModels){
                                        Log.d("Main","The movies id are: "+movieModel.getMovie_id());
                                    }
                                    moviesList.addAll(movieModels);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeMovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),moviesList));
                                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                                    if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            
                                    }
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
            
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `movieList.clear()` before you call refresh data so your data not duplicate

for example:

```
private void observePopularMoviesRequest(){ 
                    movieList.clear() //add this line 
                    movieListViewModel.searchMoviesPage(1);
                    movieListViewModel.getPopularMovies().observe(this, new Observer<List<MovieModel>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(List<MovieModel> movieModels) {
                            try {
            
                                //getting the retrieved data from the api
                                if (movieModels !=null){
                                    for (MovieModel movieModel: movieModels){
                                        Log.d("Main","The movies id are: "+movieModel.getMovie_id());
                                    }
                                    moviesList.addAll(movieModels);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new HomeMovieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),moviesList));
                                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
                                    if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            
                                    }
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
            
                    });
```